# Google TTS in Crossrider

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, crossrider

i developed Google chrome extension that contains Google TTS

i rewrite it with Crossrider to make it work in different platforms (it works great untill it comes to TTS part)

here is the code :

```
function PlayGoogleTTS(EngWord){
    voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

    msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();    

    msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1    
    msg.rate = 10; // 0.1 to 10
    msg.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
    msg.text = EngWord;
    msg.lang = 'en-US';    
    msg.voice = voices[1];

    msg.voice = voices[1]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params 

    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);  

}

// Fetch the list of voices and populate the voice options.
function loadVoices() {
  // Fetch the available voices.
    var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
}

// Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function(e) {
  loadVoices();
};
```

so how can i convert it to make it work on Crossrider?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question which speechSynthesis library/api you are using. However, assuming it is based on [Chrome's TTS API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tts), the required "tts" permission is not available.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Whilst Crossrider does not support the scenario, it is technically possible to manually add the extension permissions by downloading the Chrome Store package, editing the manifest file, and uploading the modified package to the Chrome Store. However, if you do decide to make the change, you will have to experiment on your own and do so at your own risk since Crossrider cannot support extensions modified in this way.

Answer (score 0):

it's considered workaround more than an answer

just used another TTS that able to generate ogg maves in firefox